# React-tagsinput module implementation in React Flux project; there is an error in my code for the tag functionality?

Tags: git, reactjs, flux, reactjs-flux

I've tried a few different implementations (you can see them commented out).

Once I launch the project, the screen displays an input text box with 'tag1 tag2' written in it- because that's what I intialized them as; but I can't do anything as whenever I try to manipulate them (delete/spacebar/add another letter) they get replaced by

```
[object Object]
```

in the text field and then I can't do anything still, except going back over it with arrowkeys; but if I try anything else, it'll push the cursor back to front.

---

I've tried a few variations like:
    TagsCom.React.createElement("text", null,...) or just
    TagsCom.createElement("text", null,...)
or even just replacing the TagsCom with TagsInput but the only line of code that even remotely works so far is:

```
<TagsInput value={this.state.tags} onChange={this.handleChange} />
```

And though this has solved the object problem, it's still all static text and not acting like tags

Here is my updated component code:

```
var React      = require('react');
var ReactDOM   = require('react-dom');
var TagsInput1 = require('react-tagsinput');
var TagsCom    = require('./react-tagsinput.js');
//var TagsCSS  = require('react-tagsinput/react-tagsinput.css');

var TagsComponent = React.createClass
({
    displayName    : "TagsComponent",
    getInitialState: function()
    {
        return {
            tags: ["tag1", "tag2"]
        };
    },

    saveTags: function (){
        console.log("tags: ", this.state.tags.join(", "));
    },

    handleChange: function(event){
    this.setState({tags: event.target.value});
    },

    render: function ()
    {

      <TagsInput value={this.state.tags} onChange={this.handleChange} />

    }
});
module.exports = TagsComponent;
```

and here is the git link to the react-tagsinput module that has all the other files https://github.com/olahol/react-tagsinput

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much trial and error, I've figured out the correct render function- it renames TagsInput to ReactTagsInput and leaves the onChange parameter as 'value':

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var ReactTagsInput = require('./react-tagsinput.js');

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.0/react-with-addons.js"></script>

tags:[];  
var TagsComponent = React.createClass({
    displayName: "TagsComponent",

    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            tags: ["tag1", "tag2"]
        };
    },

    saveTags: function () {
        console.log("tags: ", this.state.tags.join(", "));
    },

    handleChange: function(value){
        this.setState({tags: value});
    },

    render: function () {
        return 

    <div>
       <ReactTagsInput value={this.state.tags} onChange={this.handleChange}/>   
     </div>;
    }

    });


 module.exports = TagsComponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `input` tag's `onChange` callback has a single argument of **`event`**, not `value` as you seem to be expecting.

It should look like this;

```
handleChange: function(event){
        this.setState({tags: event.target.value});
    },
```

Comment: @gravityplax Thanks! that solved the [object Object] problem and the now all typed text is changing the value parameter :)
The only problem is that it's still not acting as a tag and just as a text input; should I include a listStore for the tag array and push new tags on that? Or am I missing something else?

Comment: Right now you are rendering a text input.  It won't become something else until you make it something else.  If you want to use that external component, you'll have to actually include it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? It should be referencing the react-tagsinput.js already, so do you mean that it's not?

Comment: It absolutely isn't.  Your commented out code is closer to using it that the currently active code.   `class="react-tagsinput"` doesn't do anything.

Comment: @gravityplax  Any advice on how to fix it? I've been stuck in this one issue for over a week now and haven't really gotten what's going wrong.